# Question regarding the syntax of someting related to macro in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

```
#define minimum(mn, b) mn = min(b) 
#define maximum(mx, c) mx = max(c)
#define INF 10000000
#define toStr(a) #a
#define io(v) v.push_back()
#define FUNCTION(a,b) #

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#if !defined toStr || !defined io || !defined FUNCTION || !defined INF
#error Missing preprocessor definitions
#endif 

FUNCTION(minimum, <)
FUNCTION(maximum, >)

int main(){
    int n; cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    foreach(v, i) {
        io(v)[i];
    }
    int mn = INF;
    int mx = -INF;
    foreach(v, i) {
        minimum(mn, v[i]);
        maximum(mx, v[i]);
    }
    int ans = mx - mn;
    cout << toStr(Result =) <<' '<< ans;
    return 0;

}
```

This is a sample question from a [hackerrank questio](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/preprocessor-solution/problem?isFullScreen=true)n, so there would be some mistakes in it. I want to know what does the part

```
FUNCTION(minimum, <)
FUNCTION(maximum, >)
```

mean ? It doesn't look like a macro as it doesn't start with `#define`. The discussion forums too didn't have a good explanation about this part, just that it relates to the macro defined as `#define minimum(mn, b) mn = min(b)` and `#define maximum(mx, c) mx = max(c)`. 
'
I want to know what's it called and some advice on good resource to read about it.

The title is poorly written as I have no clue what to refer to that doubtful part of code as.

Comment: I don't believe `#define FUNCTION(a,b) #` is valid syntax. `#` operator should precede a token.

Comment: You should "refer to that doubtful part of code as" something that no self-respecting C++ developer should be writing. Sites like "hackerrank", and similar ones, are not teaching you well-written C++, and providing useful knowledge. They're a waste of web space.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you can check the question in the link I provided.

Comment: The question at the link doesn't appear to contain `FUNCTION` at all, in any shape or form. At least not the way that page appears to a non-signed-in user, and I'm not going to create an account at that site.

Comment: It doesn't even compile (as expected): `main.cpp:6:21: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it does, you need to expand the code at line 3.

Comment: When I go to that page, I don't see any code.

Comment: You need to create an account and log in first.

Comment: I gathered as much, but I'm not going to.

Comment: Actually, no, it is there even without. just scroll to the bottom

Comment: It's not there for me, at the top or the bottom or elsewhere.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code that I posted is the one that I am working on right now. So there are mistakes, and the program won't compile. I just wanted to know what some lines there meant, so that I could go look and read about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this answer into parts:

---

First, the thing you show here isn't valid code. `#define FUNCTION(a, b) #` doesn't compile on GCC, it correctly says:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
```

`#` is supposed to work like shown in your `toStr` example, where `#a` causes it to emit a *string* with `a`'s value as contents.

---

Second, I *assume* that the poster of this "solution" wanted `FUNCTION` to just do nothing.

It seems that some compilers do treat a sole `#` that way, but it's not correct. It would have worked to write `#define FUNCTION(a, b)` without anything afterwards (or 
`#define FUNCTION(a, b) //` like I saw in some other solutions for this question).

**So, the answer to "what does this part do" is literally "nothing".** (At least, it was intended this way.)

---

Third, even with that fixed, the code doesn't look right, because unless I'm misreading this, it doesn't really calculate any minimum or maximum, because `min` doesn't get the previous minimum as argument (same for `max`)! I'd expect this...

```cpp
#define minimum(mn, b) mn = min(mn, b)
#define maximum(mx, c) mx = max(mx, c)
```

...instead of the current `min(b)` and `max(c)` there.

---

Forth, it seems that *most* solutions on this hackerrank question turn `FUNCTION` into a no-op and instead create `minimum` and `maximum` as macros.

But, I feel like the intention behind `FUNCTION` was something else, something a bit more clever. You could define it as macro that creates *functions* (hence the name) named after the first argument, that compare the minimum/maximum based on the second argument used as comparison operator:

```cpp
#define FUNCTION(_FN_NAME_, _COMPARISON_OP_) \
  void _FN_NAME_(int& limit, int newValue) { \
    if (newValue _COMPARISON_OP_ limit) { \
      limit = newValue; \
    } \
  }
```

This way, `FUNCTION(minimum, <)` and `FUNCTION(maximum, >)` would expand to:

```cpp
void minimum(int& limit, int newValue) {
  if (newValue < limit) {
    limit = newValue;
  }
}

void maximum(int& limit, int newValue) {
  if (newValue > limit) {
    limit = newValue;
  }
}
```